# How to decide which one will be Masterport and Slaveport in Gem5

Tags: memory, architecture, gem5

I was looking into build a simple architecture, where I have one or more Scratchpad memories connected to a noncoherentXBar, but before I even do that, how should one decide which port will be the master and which one will be the slave,any rule of thumb?

In the tutorial provided by Gem5 titled: "Creating SimObjects in the memory system" they have made the side connecting to the main memory as Master port while the side connecting to the CPU as the Slaveport, why was it set like this?